# getting an access denied error while building a cpp file in sublime text

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, mingw

So i downloaded sublime text and installed mingw compiler. I have verified through cmd prompt that mingw is installed correctly. I added the environment path to my compiler in settings.

I created a new build system on sublime text:

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++17", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

Above system i took from this site: https://blog.codingblocks.com/2019/setting-up-a-c-competitive-programming-environment/

Basically it takes input from inputf.in and shows output at outputf.in

When i write my program of a simple printing of "hello world" and try to build using `Cntrl + B`, i get the following error.

```
Access is denied.
[Finished in 1.1s]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanku

EDIT: It was my antivirus. Thanku to all who answered. :D

Comment: My anti virus does that. Try disabling it if you have it

Comment: You should check if the same named process's running in the background and kill if found any from Task Manager 'cause the compiler won't able to generate the executable unless the running one's in use.